# How do I calculate the RPM and torque of a 12 V DC motor that gets 5 V?

Tags: voltage, pcb, motor, torque, rpm

I have a PCB that outputs 5 V to each of the two motors. It was part of a robotics kit that included two 12 V 360 RPM motors.

I want to attach a 12 V DC motor with 3500 RPM. How do I calculate how much RPM or torque I can expect to see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The torque you see depends on how much load you actually apply to the motor. I think what you're asking is how much torque it is safe for the motor to produce.

But you can't calculate anything unless you know the stall torque of the motor at some voltage and the no-load RPM at that same voltage.

Stall torque and no-load RPM approximately scale with the voltage. So double the voltage, you double the no-load RPM and double the stall torque.

DC motors produce zero torque at no-load RPM and stall torque at zero RPM, with a straight line running between the two. In other words the torque vs RPM curve is linear.

As a rule of thumb for DC motors, maximum efficiency happens at about 1/7th of stall torque or or 6/7ths of no-load RPM (these correspond to the same point on the curve). Maximum power output happens at 1/2 of no-load RPM and 1/2 of stall torque (again, these correspond to the same point on the curve). You want to run the motor at one of these points if possible based on your priorities, or at least in between these two points.

It is better to load the motor a bit more than the torque required for maximum efficiency than to underload it since the efficiency drops off much more as you load it below this point than if you overload it.

Note that **rated** RPM and **rated** torque are different numbers. These are numbers the designers think you would probably want to run the motor at for a good compromise between efficiency and power output for the weight of the motor (as well as other usage considerations).

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you'll get about 5/12 the no-load RPM (about 1450 RPM) and about 5/12 the stall torque.